# Where are in camera ratings on the Canon 5D MkIII stored?

Tags: canon, metadata, canon-5d-mark-iii

The [Canon 5D MkIII](http://usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/slr_cameras/eos_5d_mark_iii) introduced a new featured that lets you rate images by using a dedicated rear button. I am interested in finding out where in the EXIF data that this rating is stored. I wasn't aware of any metadata field that ratings were typically stored in, so I'm not sure what they would be using.

You can read about the feature on [page 255 of the manual](http://www.canonrumors.com/files/eos5dmkiii-im-c-en.pdf). The manual notes that:

> With Windows Vista and Windows 7, you can see each files rating as part of the file information display or in the provided image viewer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly I don't have a 5DmkIII but I've managed to figure it out with a bit of detective work.

**The answer is that it's stored in an XMP header as the `<xmp:Rating>` value.**

I started by hunting down a Canon 5DmkIII group on Flickr and found [this thread](http://www.flickr.com/groups/canoneos5dmarkii/discuss/72157629295862996/). Click on one of those photos then go to the [metadata page](http://www.flickr.com/photos/kinematic/6876736012/meta/) and you'll see one of the values listed is **Rating** (in this case with a value of 3). I'm certain that value hasn't come from post-processing because the metadata also shows it was processed in Lightroom 4. I use a 5DmkII and Lightroom 4, and rate all my photos before uploading to Flickr, and yet my photos don't have a Rating value on their [metadata page](http://www.flickr.com/photos/bitrot/7068874535/meta/).

Unfortunately all the photos I checked in that group have download disabled, so I headed over to [dpreview.com's gallery of 5DmkIII test shots](http://www.dpreview.com/galleries/reviewsamples/albums/canon-eos-5d-mark-iii-preview-samples) where I found this test image:

[image]

If you click that to go through to dpreview.com you'll see one of the tags on the photo is `pre-production`. Seeing that, and knowing dpreview.com's usual approach, it's pretty certain this image is straight out of camera.

So, I got the [URL of the original image](http://www.dpreview.com/galleries/3202320681/download/1829148) and posted it into [Jeffrey's Exif Viewer](http://regex.info/exif.cgi?imgurl=http://www.dpreview.com/galleries/3202320681/download/1829148). And there it is, right in the XMP section:

```
<?xpacket begin='' id='W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d'?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/">
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
<rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/">
<xmp:Rating>0</xmp:Rating>
</rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta> 
<?xpacket end='w'?>
```

Also note there's no Software value in the metadata anywhere: a further indication that this is straight from camera.

Finally, just to be absolutely sure, I took a straight-from-camera JPEG from my 5DmkII and ran that past Jeffrey's Exif Viewer. Sure enough, no rating value.

Comment: Just found this blog post too that concludes that Canon are now adding XMP headers in camera: http://metadatamadness.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/first-confirmed-xmp-in-original-images.html

Comment: I think I've got about as far as I can now without actually going out and buying a 5DmkIII. ;)

Comment: If you go out and buy a 5DMkIII to lay this question to rest, I will award bounty points equal to all of the rep that I have to you.

Answer (score 4):

I assume the rating is included in the EXIF data. I wrote a PHP parser a while back that actually opened .JPGs exported from Lightroom as text, and read the rating as part of a batch export script.

There's some info on the addresses here: http://www.exiv2.org/tags.html

```
Tag(hex)    Tag(dec)
0x4746      18246      Exif.Image.Rating
0x4749      18249      Exif.Image.RatingPercent
```

Comment: @drewbenn: Good points! I would presume those tags are indeed used though, since the manual explicitly states that Windows Vista and Windows 7 can read the rating information.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/EXIF.html) the Ratings and RatingPercent tags are not part of EXIF 2.3 specifications but can co-exists with EXIF tags.  I figured out from my machine that Windows 7 uses this but I do not have a 5D Mark III to test if it uses the same tag.